# Reflection at the load when matching with quarter-wave impedance transformer

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

I understand that in a configuration as the one showed in the figure below, the value of $Z_T $ is chosen so $Z_{in} = Z_0 $, meaning that there would not be a reflected wave at the interface $Z_0$-Line/Load+Transformer
[image]

But why does this guarantee that there wouldn't also be reflection at the interface Transformer/Load?
My understanding is that both a reflected and a incident wave can exist in the $Z_T$ line, this would mean that not all the power is transferred to the load.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there will be a reflection at the interface between the tranformer and the load.

The reflected wave will travel back to the input interface, where part of it is transmitted back into the feedline and part is reflected again toward the load. The sum of the  first reflection (at the feedline-transformer interface), the reflected wave (reflected from the transformer-load interface), and the infinite sum of multiply reflected waves that have traveled several times forwards and backwards through the transformer, is what provides the total reflection that gives the input impedance $Z_{in}$ its final value.

In the case of perfect matching ($Z_T = \sqrt{Z_0 Z_L}$), the net effect is indeed perfect destructive interference between all of these reflections, so that all the incident power is delivered to the load.

Comment: I am a bit confused. I thought the hole point of impedance matching was to ensure that all the power was delivered to the load, but if there is a reflected wave at the transformer-load interface, isn't that power that is not being transmitted ?

Comment: Read my second paragraph.

Comment: I express myself in a wrong way, what I meant to say is that I still do not understand why there is a perfect destructive interference resulting in no total reflected wave at the load, is there any mathematical approach to explain this? I'm thinking for example in the smith chart, where at the load I won't be centred at the origin of the chart, so there should be net reflection

Comment: @diegobatt, when you do the smith chart analysis, remember you need to do the analysis of the transformer-load reflection normalized to $Z_T$. Then when you re-normalize back to the feedline impedance, you will end up with the net reflection at the center of the chart.

Comment: but that would be at the interface feedline-adapter, if I want to see the reflection at the load shouldn't I work with the chart normalise to $Z_T$? beeing that the impedance right next to the load? I can't finish to understand why being at te centre of the chart in the interface feedline-transformer implies that the reflection coefficient is also zero at the load-transformer interface

Comment: The feedline-load interface won't be at the center of the chart. It will generate a reflection. You propagate that back by $\lambda/4$ to the feed-transformer interface. Now re-normalize to the feedline $Z_0$. Now you'll be at the center of the chart.

Comment: If there was no reflection at the transformer-load interface, that would mean $Z_L=Z_T$. Then you'd end up with $Z_{in}=Z_T$, meaning non-zero reflection at the input of $\frac{Z_T-Z_0}{Z_T+Z_0}$.

Comment: If you want to see the math you can look at the Wikipedia article on [Quarter-wave transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarter-wave_impedance_transformer). Or you could just calculate the reflection from the infinite sum of back-reflections coming from multiple reflections (which is how you get the formula using tanh()).

Comment: I think that my confusion stems from "The feedline-load interface won't be at the center of the chart. It will generate a reflection" and "all the incident power is delivered to the load. " not being contradictory. Can all the power be delivered to the load while being reflection on it ?

Comment: Sorry, typo. The transformer-load interface won't be at the center of the smith chart. It will generate a reflection. Propagate that back by 1/4 wavelength (half a cycle around the smith chart). Now re-normalize to $Z_0$. Now you'll be at the center of the smith chart.

Comment: Yes, this can result in all power ending up in the load. Some of it just has to reflect back and forth a few times to get there.

Comment: Wouldn't it take a few oscillations of the wave with that wavelength until full power is being received? The first period would only contain a fraction of the power I think, and it would slowly increase with the previous reflections. What's the point though? Why not just use a cable with the same characteristic impedance as the source and load, and then there are no reflections and it's also no longer restricted to narrowband

Comment: @LewisKelsey, This is a steady state analysis, not an actual description of the behavior of the initial wavefront in a transient.  The point: Often for practical reasons the source and load don't have the same characteristic impedance, or it would be impractical to make the load (for example an antenna) match the rest of the system.